# jQuery accordion output

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I've searched several questions here to find the answer of my question but no answer was relevant to my question/problem. Here is my wired problem, yes it's wired, now know why -

I'm intended of using native/default accordion from jQuery UI - http://jqueryui.com/accordion/ in one of my client project. All the necessary code below is working fine in a standalone template but when I went through all the code and try integrate those code in my project, all the code related to accordion just stopped working.

Here is the exact code I'm using -

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Accordion</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.min.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="faqs">
        <h3>What is your name?</h3>
        <div>
            <p>My name is bla bla bla. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At dolorem nobis quibusdam rerum saepe? Asperiores dicta expedita molestiae natus nostrum.</p>
        </div>
        <h3>What is your name?</h3>
        <div>
            <p>My name is bla bla bla. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At dolorem nobis quibusdam rerum saepe? Asperiores dicta expedita molestiae natus nostrum.</p>
        </div>
        <h3>What is your name?</h3>
        <div>
            <p>My name is bla bla bla. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At dolorem nobis quibusdam rerum saepe? Asperiores dicta expedita molestiae natus nostrum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've added all the necessary CSS and JS file to css, js directory and called the `accordion()` function to a separate plugins.js file like below -

```
//Initialize FAQ Accordion
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#faqs').accordion({
        fillSpace: true,
        heightStyle: 'content',
        icons: {
            'header': 'ui-icon-circle-arrow-e',
            'headerSelected': 'ui-icon-circle-arrow-s',
        },
        event: 'mouseover',
        collapsible: true,
        active: false,
    });
});
```

It's all about the standalone template, but where I went through my project and integrated those code, the HTML code didn't make any problem but the jQuery make my work hard to find. Here is my all additional jQuery plugins that I initialized -

```
// Avoid `console` errors in browsers that lack a console.
(function() {
    var method;
    var noop = function () {};
    var methods = [
        'assert', 'clear', 'count', 'debug', 'dir', 'dirxml', 'error',
        'exception', 'group', 'groupCollapsed', 'groupEnd', 'info', 'log',
        'markTimeline', 'profile', 'profileEnd', 'table', 'time', 'timeEnd',
        'timeStamp', 'trace', 'warn'
    ];
    var length = methods.length;
    var console = (window.console = window.console || {});

    while (length--) {
        method = methods[length];

        // Only stub undefined methods.
        if (!console[method]) {
            console[method] = noop;
        }
    }
}());

// Place any jQuery/helper plugins in here.

//Home page blog post slider
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#promo-slider").owlCarousel({
        autoPlay: 3000,
        responsive: true,
        items : 5,
        itemsDesktop : [1199,5],
        itemsDesktopSmall : [979,2],
        itemsTablet : [768,2],
        itemsMobile: [479,1],
    });
});

// Sidebar Nav Initialization
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".sidebar-nav").accordion({
        accordion:true,
        speed: 500,
        closedSign: '[+]',
        openedSign: '[-]'
    });
});


//Initialize tooltip plugin
$(".social li a").tooltip();

//Initialize FAQ Accordion
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#faqs').accordion({
        fillSpace: true,
        heightStyle: 'content',
        icons: {
            'header': 'ui-icon-circle-arrow-e',
            'headerSelected': 'ui-icon-circle-arrow-s'
        },
        collapsible: true,
        active: false
    });
});
```

The live page link is - http://baherbazar.com/html/faq.php

I failed to figure out the problem as I checked the conflicts of JS/jQuery script, but nothing found.

Do you find anything wrong in my code?

Comment: What happen if you not to include `menu.js` ?

Comment: Yes, it's caused the problem. Just tried by removing that script and the normal accordion is now working. But the main problem was in plugin namespace that @Nobert told below. 

BTW, thanks for your feedback! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the file http://baherbazar.com/html/js/menu.js is overriding your plugin 'carousel'. If you give that one a different name, that might fix your problem.

Namespace/prefixing your plugins helps prevent these issues.

Comment: Thank you very much @Nobert! This is what I needed! The both script now working fine for menu and normal accordion. :)

Comment: If it solved your problem; could you accept the answer? Glad I could help.